# Turing machine that accepts $L = \{a^{n^2} | n ≥ 1 \}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I have the following language:

> $L = \{a^{n^2} | n ≥ 1 \}$

I am trying to construct a Turing machine that accepts L. My basic idea (without success) is to use a 2-tape TM where in the 2-tape compute the string with length $n^2$. After that, I wish to compare the length of the input string in the 1-tape with the length of the string on the 2-tape.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2n+1) =(n+1)^2$. The input is in unary on one tape, the other tape is a counter, initially containing a single marker. Both heads start at the left of their tapes. A step consists of;

1. If both heads are at the right end of their markers, quit; input is a square.
2. Add two markers to the right of the counter tape.
3. Return to the start of the counter tape.
4. Advance both heads as long as the counter tape still has unvisited markers.

All you're doing is computing the sum of odd numbers above until you either match the input tape (accept) or exceed it (fail).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-tape machine that achieves the task. Note that $(n+1)^2 =n^2+n+(n+1)$. The idea is that on the second tape we will keep a unary counter $i$.

At first we begin with the second tape empty. At the begin of each iteration, the head will be at the end of the second tape. The head on the first tape will be at position $i^2$. Each iteration the head on the second tape moves back to the beginning and goes again to the end of the tape and it adds an additional one at the end of the tape.
Meanwhile, the head on the first tape moves one step to the right upon each step of the head on the second tape. If the head arrives to the end of the input the machine halts. It accepts if and only if it arrives to the end in the same step of an iteration where the second tape adds one at the end of the tape (the step where we reach the value of $i^2$ for some value of $i$.

The proof of correctness can be done through induction over $i$ (prove that when we add the $i$th letter to the second tape is the moment where we have $i^2$ steps in total.