# Turing machine that accepts $L = \{a^{n^2}|n\geq 1\}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I have the following language:

$L = \{a^{n^2}|n\geq 1\}$

Hey i have been stuck on this problem for a few days now and even going through sample problems in my textbook as well as sample solutions i cant figure out how to make this turing machine to work.

I know it may be a vague question but i really could use some help figuring this one out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turing machine for unary encoded quadratic numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41416/turing-machine-for-unary-encoded-quadratic-numbers)

Comment: Another answer: [Turing machine that accepts $L = \{a^{n^2} | n ≥ 1 \}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118739/turing-machine-that-accepts-l-an2-n-%E2%89%A5-1)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/146116/755