# How to check if a number is a square with deterministic single-tape Turing Machine

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

I am trying to design a (deterministic) one tape Turing machine that can accepts the following language L = {0^{n^2} | n belongs to N} , but so far i couldn't find a proper solutions, neither in similar questions.

I know it's a pretty general problem, but I'm stacked so far and I'm not having any good idea. Thanks in advance, any hint is welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turing machine for unary encoded quadratic numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41416/turing-machine-for-unary-encoded-quadratic-numbers)

Comment: Unfortunately no, the suggested solution uses a non-deterministic TM, while I have to use a deterministic one

Comment: Or this question: [Turing machine that accepts $L=\{ a^{n^2} \mid n\ge 1\}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118739/turing-machine-that-accepts-l-an2-n-%E2%89%A5-1) which is marked as duplicate, but its answers contain a lot of imformation.

Comment: In this one, they solve it using a two-tape Turing machine, and unfortunately I have to use a single tape...

Comment: Link should point to the duplicate question now. Also rather than guessing the right power of two, the machine can check them one by one in an deterministic approach.

Comment: Thank you, the link now works. Still, in this one, they solve it using a two-tape Turing machine, and unfortunately I have to use a single tape... I was thinking about checking all the possible n, but I can't figure out how to do it on a single tape

Comment: You can implement the 2-tape TM solution into a single tape TM by combining the contents of the two tapes into the single tape. The idea is to use a separator, e.g. #. So you will have in your tape the input $a^{n^2} $ followed by # then finally the counter. Simulate the simultaneous changes in the two tapes by 2 separate steps in your single tape TM.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I represent adding more cells to my original  input tape as a state? I never encountered it in my previous exercises, I used just to substitue existing symbols on my tape

Comment: You don't need to add new cells, since the tape has infinite cells. What you want to do in your state is to check if you have scanned passed the right-most non-blank symbol. At this point you can write a new symbol to increase the contents of your tape.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea to generate squares iteratively using the formula $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + (2n+1)$ was suggested in answers to earlier questions like

- [Turing machine for unary encoded quadratic numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41416/turing-machine-for-unary-encoded-quadratic-numbers)
- [Turing machine that accepts $L=\{ a^{n^2} \mid n\ge 1\}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118739/turing-machine-that-accepts-l-an2-n-%E2%89%A5-1)

This basic setup can be applied regardless of the Turing Machine model. A nondeterministic approach guesses the value of $n$ and compares the generated number with the input, a deterministic model will check the successive squares until the input size is less than the square.

Also the number of tapes is not an issue. Apart from the input on the tape there is ample space to the neccessary computations. Alternatively one can generate $n^2$ in the same space that is taken by the input. Just "cross out" 1,3,5,7, etc input $0$'s until either all $0$'s are gone (and we accept) or there are not enough $0$'s available (and we reject).

The language of squares is a context-sensitive language. That means it can be accepted by a deterministic Turing Machine that uses no additional space except the space taken by the input.