# Non-deterministic Turing machine that decides the language $L = \{0^{n^2} | n \geq 1\}$

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem, nondeterminism

I was trying to figure out how can I construct a non-deterministic Turing machine that decides the language $L = \{0^{n^2} | n \geq 1\}$
I looked at some of the proposed solutions here :
[Turing machine for unary encoded quadratic numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41416/turing-machine-for-unary-encoded-quadratic-numbers)
and here:
[How to check if a number is a square with deterministic single-tape Turing Machine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149176/how-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-square-with-deterministic-single-tape-turing-machi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And I came up with the following idea that uses a 4-tape Turing machine

```
M = "On input w:  
        1. Initially, tape 1 contains the input w and tapes 2,3,4 are empty.
        2. Copy tape 1 to tape 2 and start guessing on tape 3 the number 'n' using 
           non-determinism by writing 0's and then at some point moving to the next step.
        3. Copy tape 3 to tape 4.
        4. Mock the mechanism of a 'nested for loop' by first crossing off 0's in tape 3
           and then crossing off all the 0's in tape 4, on each step of crossing in tape 4 we will
           also cross 0's on tape 2 (input copy). If all 0's on tape 2 were crossed, accept. Otherwise, reject"
```

Since this is the first question I'm dealing with that involves describing a Turing machine, I feel a little bit unconfident about stage 4.
My main doubt is, given that I can construct a Turing machine that mocks the mechanism of a 'nested for loop', does it allow me to use this mechanism when describing a Turing machine ?

Comment: Or, you might make use of the fact that $1+3+5+\dots + (2n-1)=n^2$

Comment: @RickDecker I was asked to construct a non-deterministic Turing machine so I wanted to take advantage of using non-determinism for solving this problem. Do you spot something wrong with my approach ?